# Exp. Share and Pokérus in second generation (GSC)

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

Does the Exp. Share item divide EVs? And if the Pokémon (the sweeper and the Exp. Share-holder) have Pokérus, do they get the divided EVs times 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify, EVs did not exist in the second generation. [Stat experience took their place instead.](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values)

In second generation, Exp. Share does [half the stat experience](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Exp._Share). Any Pokemon with Pokerus has their stat experience gain doubled, as you said; both the sweeper and Exp. Share holder would have 50%*2 = 100% of the stat experience each.

In future generations, where EVs exist, the Exp. Share does not divide EVs. Both Pokemon would receive the full amount of EVs. This gain would also be doubled from Pokerus.